# Add the ability to use tabulation in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

Yes, we can convert tabs to spaces via Sublime, VS-Code and etc, it's not a big problem.

But what if I want to get rid off this additional action ?

**[Found](https://gist.github.com/Yardanico/1ff3181aaf28efada551713652c5eb13) answer** by adding this line to `.nim` file :

```
#? replace(sub = "\t", by = "    ")
```

My additional question is :
What is this `#?`, how this thing works and what kind of variations I can find also, for example:
#!
#some_chinese_character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a "source code filter", it's like a Nim preprocessor less powerful than macros and templates. You can read about it here: https://nim-lang.org/docs/filters.html

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend using it, but rather using an editor which replaces tabs with spaces, such as vscode. This seems more like an hack than an actual solution.